# Detect Contours using OpenCV after cropping image in Ionic application

Tags: angular, opencv, ionic-framework

I followed a blog to capture image and crop it using Ionic+angular framework.
[link](https://ionicacademy.com/image-crop-ionic-angular/)

Now, I want to detect contours using OpenCV on the cropped Image.

Can someone tell me how to do it ?

*please help and thanks in advance*

I tried various solution (like adding canvas element to HTML code , creating canvas element and then trying to draw image from the objectURL provided by the ImageCroppedEvent) but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I really hope you aren't using OpenCV version ***three point oh*** because that's years past "end of life" (death)

Comment: I am using npm package @techstark/opencv-js which is using opencv 4.7.0

Comment: I only ask because your question's tags used to indicate that.